# EF Core - Order by on filtered left join properties

Tags: entity-framework-core, left-join, sql-order-by

I would like to generate this SQL query in entity framework

```
SELECT FunctionalAssets.Name, FunctionalAssetStructurePath.Path
FROM FunctionalAssets
LEFT JOIN FunctionalAssetStructurePath ON FunctionalAssets.Id =
FunctionalAssetStructurePath.FunctionalAssetId AND
FunctionalAssetStructurePath.StructureConfigurationId = 'A8A41B14-0A35-45D3-2A2B-08D904A3CD0B'
ORDER BY FunctionalAssetStructurePath.Path, FunctionalAssets.Name
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

I try with this code (but I know that it won't work)

```
var result = context.FunctionalAssets
    .Include(x => x.FunctionalAssetsStructurePaths.Any(y => y.StructureConfigurationId == configurationId))
    .OrderBy(x => x.FunctionalAssetsStructurePaths.Select(y => y.Path))
    .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(100)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Have you an idea how to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
var result = context.FunctionalAssets
    .GroupJoin(context.FunctionalAssetStructurePathModel.Where(y => y.StructureConfigurationId == 'A8A41B14-0A35-45D3-2A2B-08D904A3CD0B'),
        fa => fa.Id,
        fasp => fasp.FunctionalAssetId,
        (fa, fasp) => new { fa, fasp })
    .SelectMany(x => x.fasp.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, p) => new { x.fa, p.Path })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Path)
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(100)
    .ToList();
```

And the generated SQL query is :

```
SELECT [f].[Id], [f].[Name], [t].[Path]
FROM [FunctionalAssets] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [f0].[FunctionalAssetId], [f0].[Path]
    FROM [FunctionalAssetStructurePath] AS [f0]
    WHERE [f0].[StructureConfigurationId] = 'A8A41B14-0A35-45D3-2A2B-08D904A3CD0B'
) AS [t] ON [f].[Id] = [t].[FunctionalAssetId]
ORDER BY [t].[Path]
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```